# MYSQL DBDump Error message

Tags: mysql

I need to get a DBDUMP, i am using MySQL.
I get the following error when i try to get a DB Dump. Any clue what it did wrong.

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin>mysqldump -u root -p xxx myDB
e >  dump.sql
Enter password: ***
mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'xxx' when selecting the database
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That command is saying you want to enter the password at the prompt and dump the `myDB` table from the `xxx` database. If you get rid of the "xxx" part and enter the password at the prompt, it should work.

If you actually want to specify the password on the command line, you have to do `-pWHATEVER` (where "WHATEVER" is the literal password, with no space after the switch), or `--password=WHATEVER`, but:

> Specifying a password on the command line should be considered insecure.

[Documentation link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_password)

Answer (score 1):

you should delete the xxx behind the -p , because the is type int the next line at the Enter password, and you should write your database name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid warning "Specifying a password on the command line should be considered insecure." just use option  --defaults-extra-file

For example:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/auth.tmp --user=xxx --tables dbname  --host localhost
```

Where /tmp/auth.tmp content is

```
[client]
password=yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use localhost with basic `user=root,password=<blank>` just copy this `mysqldump -d -u root -l dbname`